# add_action to only be called if uploading media from the front end

Tags: shortcode, uploads

I have written a shortcode which allows some users to upload to the media folder. This is done using the wp_enqueue_media scripts.

I would like to add an action which fires when a user uploads this way, so I can identify the image and apply a property to it (basically I want the media to go into a CatFolders folder if uploaded this way)

Comment: You could look into this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_dir/